# I'm getting a weird save error on ElementTree

Tags: python, key, elementtree

my current program has to change a xml value, for this I use ElementTree with this configuration:

```
for file in sorted:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    value = root.find(".//*[@key='GainedXP']").text

    root.find(value).text = 9999999
    ET.tostring(root)
```

But the code doesn't change any value and python crashes and tips to master it...

Comment: And it's kinda funny cause my tags are a nice rhyme xD

Comment: `...getting a weird save error ...` When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: [This example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) from the documentation shows finding the tag then assigning a new value to that tag's text attribute.  Is that what you are doing? Maybe you could adapt that example to your situation.

Comment: The error is: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' "

Comment: Then one of those two `find` operations are returning None. The Traceback will tell you which - that's why it is important to include the complete Traceback in your question. If your code relies on processing data your [mcve] should include a minimal example of the data - **just** enough code and data to reproduce the problem, even if you need to *construct* a toy example for us. Sometimes constructing a mre for the question will highlight the problem for **you**. did you try adapting the example in the docs?

Comment: In my program: `file means data.xml`

Comment: Where is the error message, and the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved the issue on my own. I read the new documentary again and noticed that I have to write:

```
tree.write(f)
```

insetad of:

```
ET.tostring(root)
```

Cheers